Approximation theorem's proof
Theorem Let $(X,\mathcal{M}$ a measurable space, $f:X\to[0,+\infty]$ a measurable function. Then, exists a sequence $(s_n)_n$ of simple functions st $0\leq s_1\leq...\leq s_n\leq s_{n+1}\leq f$ and $s_n(x)\overset{n}{\longrightarrow} f(x)$, $\hspace{3pt} x\in X$.
Furthermore, if $f(X)\subseteq (0,+\infty)$ and $f$ is bounded, $(s_n)_n$ uniformly converges to $f$.
Proof.
Define $s_0=0$ and $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}^\ast$ consider the interval $[0,n)$. Divide $[0,n)$ in subintervals of the form $[a,b)$ of length $2^{-n}$.
$\forall j\in\{1,...,n2^{n}\}$ define $E_{n,j}=f^{-1}\left(\left[\frac{j-1}{2^n},\frac{j}{2^n}\right)\right)$. Because $f$ is measurable, $E_{n,j}\in \mathcal{M}, \hspace{4pt} \forall j$.
We then define the set $E_n=f^{-1}\left((n,+\infty]\right)$. So, $E_n\in \mathcal{M}$ and we define $$s_n=\sum_{j=1}^{n2^n} \frac{j-1}{2^n}\mathbf{1}_{E_{n,j}}+n\mathbf{1}_{E_n}$$
If $x\in X$ and $f(x)<+\infty$, for $n>[f(x)]$ (inferior integer part), we have $$f(x)-2^{-n}<s_n(x)\leq f(x)$$
For comparison, passing to the limit for $n\to +\infty$, we conclude that $s_n(x)\to f(x)$.
If $x\in X$ and $f(x)=+\infty\hspace{4pt}$, $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}\hspace{4pt}$, $s_n(x)=n\to +\infty$.
In the additional hypothesis, if $n>[\sup(f)]$ (inferior integer part), we have $$f(x)-2^{-n}<s_n(x)\leq f(x)$$
Therefore, $\lim_n \sup_{x\in X}|s_n(x)-f(x)|\leq \lim_n 2^{-n}=0$.
So, the convergence is uniform.
$\Box$
I'm not sure about two things, the first is why $E_n$ is define in that way and the second is how it's proven the uniform convergence. Any help?

The definition of the uniform convergence is exactly $\lim_n \sup_{x\in X}|s_n(x)-f(x)|=0$. What is your definition of it ?

And the idea behind the definition of $E_n$ is that at a step $n$, $s_n$ will approximate quite precisely $f$ up to values smaller than $n$. We have to approximate $f$ up to a certain value at each step $n$ of the process, because simple functions must have finitely many indicator functions in them, so we can’t be greater than a certain value at each step, and this approximation randomly choose the value at $n$ for the $n$-th step.

For the uniform convergence, I have the same definition, I was just wondering if I calculated correctly.

So, $En$ allows me to cover everything that simple functions don't take beyond $[0,n)$?

For the uniform convergence you have made a mistake writing an equal signe instead of a smaller or equal, but in the end yes you get 0.

$E_n$ is used in a simple function, but it is the one representing the value at which the approximation might become not so good.

I've made an edit for the uniform convergence, is it now correct?

Yes it is correct.

Okay, thank you.
